# Using jQuery to call an API, and then refresh the contents of the div containing the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, post

I have a page with a form inside a div. Submitting the form refreshes the div's containing page. When I submit the form, jQuery does not interrupt the submit of the form and execute.

My Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/js/jquery.prod.2.2.0.js"></script>
<script>
$("#genericForm").on('submit', function(e) {
    console.log("Here");
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/app.php";
           data: $(this).serialize(),
           success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
         }
    });
e.preventDefault();
return false;
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method=post action="/app.php" id="genericForm"> 
<input name=firstname type=text>
<input name=lastname type=text>
<input name=nickname type=text>
<input type=submit>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try moving `e.preventDefault();` to the top of the function. Dunno if that will work or not.

Comment: With the e.preventDefault(); at the top of the function, the code still does not execute.

Comment: Instead of using an `<input type="submit">`, why not just use a `<span>` or a `<div>` tag. And then use `$(jquery_selector).on('click'...`. It will make your life easier. :-)

Comment: Because I want to use this function on various forms that will be submitted on select box changes, check box changes, and "enter presses". So capturing a span works on some pages, but not for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, You have a syntax error here:

```
url: "/app.php";
```

You need a comma instead of semicolon:

```
url: "/app.php",
```

Also, you need to put your code inside a `$(document).ready` event handler to make it work. As you have put your code before you have put the form, it is executed immediately which doesn't find any form in the DOM. So fix it like this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#genericForm").on('submit', function(e) {
        console.log("Here");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/app.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I see the error. I fixed it and I'm still not getting and content in the console log. the page forwards to /app.php.

Answer (score 0):

> Syntax error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` breaks the `submit handler`

It is not somehow related with `e.preventDefault();`

There is a syntax error here:

```
url: "/app.php";
______________^^
```

It must be `,` like this: `url: "/app.php",`

Try this:

```js
$("#genericForm").on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Here");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/app.php",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method=post action="/app.php" id="genericForm">
  <input name=firstname type=text>
  <input name=lastname type=text>
  <input name=nickname type=text>
  <input type=submit>
</form>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/rck36s7v/)

Comment: Thanks Rayon, TaReQ already pointed out the error, but the change still doesn't execute the code. I have moved the e.preventDefault(); and changed the ; to a , but the code still does not execute.

Comment: I have attached fiddle url in my answer. I hope that helps. If it does not then check the console for errors or the `url` or the response which is being received ;)

Answer (score -1):

`e.preventDefault` blocks the default behaviour of the element. But it should be placed just before doing any other task rather than the default functionality.

```
$("#genericForm").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/app.php";
           data: $(this).serialize(),
           success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: As Richard suggested I moved the e.preventDefault(); to the beginning of the function, but no joy.

Answer (score -1):

As Richard suggested in the comments, try moving the `e.preventDefault()` to the top of the function. It is likely that the submission and refresh is happening before the `e.preventDefault()` is registered.